# some scala grammar when I read the source code of spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

1、what does the  =>  mean here?

```
 import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.{ALS => NewALS}
```

2、what does the '@' mean before the function?

```
  @DeveloperApi
    def setIntermediateRDDStorageLevel(storageLevel: StorageLevel): this.type = {
        require(storageLevel != StorageLevel.NONE,
          "ALS is not designed to run without persisting intermediate RDDs.")
        this.intermediateRDDStorageLevel = storageLevel
        this
    }
```

is it a decorator for the function?

Comment: `ALS => NewALS` -  it is renamve of the import. Now in the code you could use NewALS instead of ALS. Such construction could be usefull if you are using classes with the same name but from different package.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know what does the @ mean?

Comment: @ - (in provided example) is for marking with annotation. `@DeveloperApi ` - means that you mark function with annotation. If you go to the `org.apache.spark.annotation.DeveloperApi` you will find definition of this annotation.

Comment: Can you copy these comments into an answer, please? :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

ALS => NewALS - it is renamve of the import. Now in the code you could use NewALS instead of ALS. Such construction could be usefull if you are using classes with the same name but from different package.  ---- by @baju

@ - (in provided example) is for marking with annotation. @DeveloperApi - means that you mark function with annotation. If you go to the org.apache.spark.annotation.DeveloperApi you will find definition of this annotation.    ----  by @baju